# Распарс XML в SQL

Tags: sql, xml, парсер, plsql

### Здравствуйте,

С помощью кода **PL SQL** я получаю ответ от сервера в ввиде строки **XML**.

Вот, собственно, сам код, которым я получаю ***XML***.

```
create or replace procedure publish_cinema_even
is
  req utl_http.req;
  res utl_http.resp;
  url varchar2(4000) := 'https://alsytto.onlyoffice.eu/api/2.0/authentication.xml?userName=roma@roma.by&password=password';
  name varchar2(4000);
  buffer varchar2(4000); 
  content varchar2(4000) := '{}';

begin
  utl_http.set_wallet ('file:c:\app\wallet2','test1234');
  utl_http.set_detailed_excp_support (true);
  req := utl_http.begin_request(url, 'POST',' HTTP/1.1');

  --UTL_HTTP.set_wallet('file:/c:\app\oraUser\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\BIN\wallets', 'test1234');
  --utl_http.set_header(req, 'user-agent', 'mozilla/4.0'); 
  --utl_http.set_header(req, 'content-type', 'application/json'); 
  utl_http.set_header(req, 'Content-Length', length(content));

  utl_http.write_text(req, content);
  res := utl_http.get_response(req);
  -- process the response from the HTTP call
  begin 
    loop
      utl_http.read_line(res, buffer);
      dbms_output.put_line(buffer);
    end loop;
    utl_http.end_response(res);
  exception
    when utl_http.end_of_body 
    then
      utl_http.end_response(res);
  end;
end publish_cinema_even;
```

#### И после получаю такой ответ от сервера:

```
<result><count>1</count><status>0</status><statusCode>201</statusCode><response><token>oAf5U23dQqn0cSQzNuOwN7CLW7R+fiv4xV5Te7/YZ9IERMivUwUiQA9abO2U+maXGgygOwIZtLoLWFN04q1k4AV0+vGOsJiQadjt+4iOq0vs5mNImF5DsknhPsN9qA1N</token><expires>2017-09-14T10:53:56.2760087+03:00</expires><sms>false</sms><phoneNoise /></response></result>
```

#### Помогите распарсить этот ответ и записать token в переменную.

Answer (score 1):

Для получения token из xml находящего в переменной `buffer` в переменную `token` используйте следующий запрос:

```
 select extractValue(xmltype(buffer),'//token') into token from DUAL;
```